# How to force all "or"

Tags: python

Because of "short-circuit operator", Python only evaluates the second argument if the first one is False.

I have a function like this:

```
def calcule_deplacements_possibles(self, y, x, idx, pp):
    idp = pp['id']
    if pp['piece'] == 'abeille':
        o = False
        o = self.glissement_test(y, x, -2, 0, -1, -1, -1, +1, idp) or o
        o = self.glissement_test(y, x, -1, +1, -2, 0, +1, +1, idp) or o
        o = self.glissement_test(y, x, +1, +1, -1, +1, +2, 0, idp) or o
        o = self.glissement_test(y, x, +2, 0, +1, +1, +1, -1, idp) or o
        o = self.glissement_test(y, x, +1, -1, +2, 0, -1, -1, idp) or o
        o = self.glissement_test(y, x, -1, -1, +1, -1, -2, 0, idp) or o
        if o:
            self.board[y][x]['b'][idx]['m'] = True
```

This is hexagonal type of cells so I need to try all of them, because `glissement_test()` adds some markers, so it has *always* to be called (here 6 times).

How to "force" those calls and use the results like in my code?

Comment: @snakecharmerb it would not call all the functions 6 times with an `and` if one evaluate to false

Comment: You're already "forcing" those calls by putting them on the left side of the `or`. Are you looking for a better way, or did you not realize your existing code was fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through each set of values you'd like to use, and then see whether they all occurred:

```
tests = [self.glissement_test(y, x, *vals, idp) for vals in ((-2, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1),
                                                             (-1, 1, -2, 0, 1, 1),
                                                             (1, 1, -1, 1, 2, 0),
                                                             (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1),
                                                             (1, -1, 2, 0, -1, -1),
                                                             (-1, -1, 1, -1, -2, 0))]

if any(tests):
    self.board[y][x]['b'][idx]['m'] = True
```

Note that integer literals are positive by default, so you don't need to specify e.g. `+1` to get positive 1.

Comment: `all(tests)` would correspond to `and`, using `any(tests)` would be the equivalent of the OP's `or`.

Comment: `and` stops evaluating when something turns up as false, whereas `or` stops evaluating when something turns up as true. In this, all the tests have been carried out already as desired, so it's okay to short-circuit when checking whether they were all successful.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah, but we're not supposed to check whether they were all successful. We're supposed to check whether any of them were successful.

Comment: Nice Python-way of writing, I'll add this to my slide for comparison between Python beginners and Python-like code **`:^D`**

Comment: FYI I specify +1 to get positive 1 so that indentation is the same all over the place, same for "+0" (otherwise I get warning in PyCharm too....)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to turn off short-circuiting in Python (nor is there a short-circuit-free "or" operator) as far as I'm aware.

Code in a conditional shouldn't "do" things anyway, hence the convention of short-circuiting in most languages.

Compute the result of `self.glissement_test` *first*, assigning it to a variable, then check `<that variable> or o`.

Answer (score 0):

If `glissement_test()` somehow mutates state of `self` do not use it in conditional. It confuses person reading a code and makes your intent unclear.

Explicitly call all values, and then run a check:

```
t1 = self.glissement_test(y, x, -2, 0, -1, -1, -1, +1, idp)
t2 = self.glissement_test(y, x, -1, +1, -2, 0, +1, +1, idp)
t3 = self.glissement_test(y, x, +1, +1, -1, +1, +2, 0, idp)
t4 = self.glissement_test(y, x, +2, 0, +1, +1, +1, -1, idp)
t5 = self.glissement_test(y, x, +1, -1, +2, 0, -1, -1, idp)
t6 = self.glissement_test(y, x, -1, -1, +1, -1, -2, 0, idp)

# Now do the check
if t1 or t2 or t3 or t4 or t5 or t6:
    self.board[y][x]['b'][idx]['m'] = True
```